# Swift - How to change badge color of UITabItem programatically?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, badge

I want to change color of badge of barItem programatically from default red color.

[image: Badge example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify it through UITabBar.appearance()

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            SomeContent()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab1", systemImage: "star")
                }
            
            SomeContent()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab2", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .badge(10)
        }
        .onAppear() {
            let appearance  = UITabBarAppearance()
            
            //portrait
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .green
            
            //landscape
            appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .blue
            
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
}
```